# Entity Framework Query - Unable to fetch data

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am working on a WPF application and using Entity framework 6.0

**I have written following query to fetch data from database but could not fetch any data:**

```
var customersList = context.Customers.Include(x => x.ReturnedCustomerItems.Select(y => y.ReturnedLotItem)).Where(x => x.IsDeleted != false).ToList();
```

**Notes:**

```
1. context: Database Context Object
2. Customers: DbSet for Customer's table
3. ReturnedCustomerItems: List of Customer Items to be returned.
4. ReturnedLotItem: Lot Item corresponding to Returned Customer Item. Each Customer Item will have a corresponding lot item..
```

Following is the SQL Query I have written to check whether data exits inside database:

```
select * from 
transportapp.dbo.customer cust,
transportapp.dbo.ReturnedCustomerItem ret,
transportapp.dbo.ReturnedLotItem item
where 
cust.CustomerId = ret.CustomerId
and ret.BookingItemId = item.BookingItemId
```

As output I got the following data records:

[image]

Following is the Table structure generated by Entity Framework:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ReturnedCustomerItem] (
    [BookingItemId]   INT             NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted]       BIT             NOT NULL,
    [CustomerId]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [ReturnCharge]    DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [DemurrageCharge] DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Weight]          DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Quantity]        INT             NOT NULL,
    [ReturnDate]      DATETIME        NOT NULL,
    [Status]          NVARCHAR (100)  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ReturnedCustomerItem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BookingItemId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ReturnedCustomerItem_dbo.Customer_CustomerId] FOREIGN KEY ([CustomerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([CustomerId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ReturnedCustomerItem_dbo.ReturnedLotItem_BookingItemId] FOREIGN KEY ([BookingItemId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ReturnedLotItem] ([BookingItemId])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ReturnedLotItem] (
    [BookingItemId]   INT             NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted]       BIT             NOT NULL,
    [IsReturned]      BIT             NOT NULL,
    [ReturnCharge]    DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [DemurrageCharge] DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Weight]          DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Quantity]        INT             NOT NULL,
    [LotId]           INT             NOT NULL,
    [LotItemId]       INT             NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ReturnedLotItem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BookingItemId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ReturnedLotItem_dbo.BookingItem_BookingItemId] FOREIGN KEY ([BookingItemId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[BookingItem] ([BookingItemId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ReturnedLotItem_dbo.ReturnedLot_LotId] FOREIGN KEY ([LotId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ReturnedLot] ([LotId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ReturnedLotItem_dbo.LotItem_LotItemId] FOREIGN KEY ([LotItemId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[LotItem] ([BookingItemId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I am unable to debug the LINQ expression where I am going wrong. Need help in identifying the mistake.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my silly mistake....

Here is the correct LINQ expression:

```
var customersList = context.Customers.Include(x => x.ReturnedCustomerItems.Select(y => y.ReturnedLotItem)).Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList();
```